# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `open` of type `function` supplied to `ForwardRef(Dialog)`, expected `boolean`. at Dialog

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The idea is to show a District Overview in a dialog box and then display a table once the dialog box is closed. However, I cannot seem to get rid of the box when I click on close. The Dialog Box comes up when the By District Option is clicked(marked in Yellow) which then brings up a dropdown(marked in Red). Once a value in the dropdown is selected the Dialog Box comes up. Although the dialog box shows up, I cannot seem to close it somehow. The console gives the error I gave in the title. The screenshots and the code are below:

[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './advance_filter.css';
import DistrictFilter from "../../widgets/filter_dropdowns/district_filter/district_filter";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import { DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogTitle } from "@material-ui/core";

const AdvanceFilterScreen = () => {

    const [byDistrictFilter, setByDistrictFilter] = useState(false);     //This is the hook that selects the By District option
    const [district, setDistrict] = useState('');                       //This selects the value from the Dropdown

    const [districtDialogOpen, setDistrictDialogOpen] = useState(false);  //This was meant for opening and closing the dialog box


    const districtFilter = () => {
        setByDistrictFilter(prev => !prev);
        setFilterButtonValue('');
        setDistrict('')
    }

    const openDialog = () => {
        setDistrictDialogOpen(prev => !prev)
    }

    const closeDialog = () => {
        setDistrictDialogOpen(prev => !prev);
    }

    return (
        <div className="advanceFilterScreen">
            <div className="navBarFilter">
                <NavBar></NavBar>
            </div>
            <div className="chooseFilters">
                <div className="chooseColumn">
                    <div className="caption">Choose Filters (Upto 5 filters at a time)</div>
                    <div className="filterOptions">
                        <div onClick={districtFilter}>
                            <div className={byDistrictFilter ? "districtSelectedFilter" : "byDistrictFilter"}>By District</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={byDistrictFilter ? "filterDropdowns" : "noFilter"}>
                <div className="filterClass">
                    {byDistrictFilter ? <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
                        {/* This shows the District Dropdown */}
                        <DistrictFilter setDistrict={setDistrict}></DistrictFilter>
                    </div> : null}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {district ? <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={closeDialog}>
                        <DialogTitle className="districtOverview">{"District Overview"}</DialogTitle>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <div className="overAll">
                                {/* This component shows the overview on the Dialog Box */}
                                <DistrictTable district={district} setFilterButtonValue={setFilterButtonValue} ></DistrictTable>
                            </div>
                        </DialogContent>
                        <DialogActions>
                            <div className="closeButton" onClick={closeDialog}>Close</div>
                        </DialogActions>
                    </Dialog>
                        : <FilterSearchButton district={district}></FilterSearchButton>}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
                <Table buttonValue={buttonValue}></Table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AdvanceFilterScreen;
```

In case someone needs the CSS file for testing:

```
.advanceFilterScreen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navBarFilter {
    background-color: rgb(52, 171, 245);
}

.chooseFilters {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: rgb(52, 171, 245);
}

.chooseColumn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
}

.caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.filterOptions {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.byNameFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.nameSelectedFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.byDateFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.dateSelectedFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.byCategoryFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.categorySelectedFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.byDistrictFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.districtSelectedFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.byStatesFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.stateSelectedFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.bySerialNumberFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.serialNumberSelectedFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.byIssueFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.issueSelectedFilter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.filterDropdowns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(52, 171, 245);
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
}

.noFilter {
    display: none;
}

.filterClass {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
    /* width: 100%;
    height: 50px; */
    /* background-color: yellow; */
}

.districtOverview {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.overAll {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    /* background-color: red; */
}

.closeButton {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    color: rgb(52, 171, 245);
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* .searchFilterButton {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(52, 171, 245);
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
} */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open prop passed to dialog isn't meant to be a function. It should be a boolean. The trigger of the District Overview dialog should be the state of district, when district has a truthy value. So it's either you render using a tenary operator `district ? /* dialog */ : /* filter button */` and have
the oepn prop set to true on initial render or you render the dialog immediately with the other nodes and set its open prop to `open={Boolean(district)}`

```js
const districtFilter = () => {
  setByDistrictFilter(prev => !prev);
  setFilterButtonValue('');
}

const closeDialog = () => {
  setDistrict('')
}
```

```
<div>
  {district ? (
    <Dialog open onClose={closeDialog}>
      {/* ... */}
    </Dialog>
  ) : (
    <FilterSearchButton district={district}></FilterSearchButton>
  )}
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
  <Dialog open={Boolean(district)} onClose={closeDialog}>
    {/* ... */}
  </Dialog>
  
  {district && <FilterSearchButton district={district}></FilterSearchButton>}
</div>
```